# Use embedded file from .exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, exe, 7zip

I made an exe that has embedded files in it like a portable 7zip (7za.exe) and I want to call to it in the batch script that I am compiling into an exe but when I do it just gives me "7za.exe" is not recognized as an internal or external command. If I left anything out just ask.

(Sorry if this is an easy fix I am just messing around with some basic code)

This is the code I am working with and exe is in releases tab.

https://github.com/iamtis/mass-extract

Comment: This error means that the script doesn't know where to find 7za.exe. Either stick it in the same folder as your script, add the location of the program to your path variable, or use the full path to the program in your script.

Comment: Ok I will try some of these things but is there any way of extracting a .rar without winrar that is open source because I know 7zip can open rar but can it extract with the portable version.

Comment: @IamTis UnRar.exe is freeware. Just Rar.exe and WinRAR.exe are shareware. You should really read the manuals/helps of the tools you want to use for your batch tool converted to an executable.

Comment: @Mofi Yes I should but this isn't for distrubution or anything so I wasn't really worried about it getting taken down or anything like that but I will in the future

Answer (score 0):

Let us look on batch file with some additional lines at top:

```
@echo off
echo Current working directory is: %CD%
echo Directory of batch file is:   %~dp0
pause
echo Files in current working directory:
dir /A-D /B
pause
echo Files in directory of batch file:
dir /A-D /B "%~dp0"
pause
```

I suppose that the current working directory is not equal the directory of the batch file and the tools are in the directory of the batch file. I suppose the batch file directory is a subdirectory with random name in `%TEMP%`.

So what you most likely need is:

```
@echo off
set "ToolPath=%~dp0"
if not exist "%CD%\archive\*" md "%CD%\archive"
"%ToolPath%7za.exe" x "%CD%\*.zip" "%CD%\archive\"
"%ToolPath%7za.exe" x "%CD%\*.7z" "%CD%\archive\"
"%ToolPath%unrar.exe" x "%CD%\*.rar" "%CD%\archive\"
"%ToolPath%7za.exe" a -mx9 archive.7z "%CD%\archive\"
rd /S /Q "%CD%\archive"
set "ToolPath="
```

Comment: Ok so the files are located in %MYFILES% and they have the same names like 7za.exe so the program runs except it doesn't extract the files all it does is make a folder called archive make a 7z file of it (with nothing in it) and deletes archive so my problem now is finding why it will compress but no extract.

Comment: So all I need to do is figure out why it isn't targeting the files, I forget where but I think 7za uses different then just * but I can't remember.